# from where do i start to learn game ai

Tags: ai

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New to creating AI - where to start?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/new-to-creating-ai-where-to-start)

i have been programming 2-3 games till now. but i have not used ai in any of them...so can u please suggest good ebooks or net articles or tutorials on game ai...problems featuring shortest path, pathfinding etc...
Thankyou