# Useful resources for beginning AI

Tags: ai, assets, books

What resources are available, including both free articles/ebooks and physical books and things, for game developers looking to begin simple AI programming/design?

*Note: [I know of this question,](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/new-to-creating-ai-where-to-start) but that's more asking about where to start on a specific topic; I'm more asking about resources in general.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Programming Game AI By Example](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1556220782) by Mat Buckland is an excellent resource to get started. He starts right from the basics of state machines and moves on to steering behaviours and graph theory for pathfinding. Probably one of the best resources I've found, especially when starting out.

The [AI Game Wisdom](http://www.aiwisdom.com/) books are also very good, but a lot of the articles are pretty advanced.

A good link for steering behaviours is this site: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/

And as has been mentioned, http://aigamedev.com has amazing content, right from the frontlines.

Amit's Game Programming site is pretty decent at getting an overview (although admittedly, I haven't used it much): http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html#ai

I'd thoroughly recommended Buckland's book though. Very easy to follow and the source code actually works :)

Ray

Comment: I've heard loads of great things about the Buckland book, and the only problem is that it is slightly too expensive for a student not yet into uni, like all programming books I guess. :P

Comment: On the link that I've provided it's around 30 pound, which for a programming book is relatively cheap. I'd highly recommend it and a load of people I know (including my games lecturer) swear by it :)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a really big fan of this book in terms of 'simple',

[AI for Game Developers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596005555)

You can find it for about $5.00 on Amazon if you factor in shipping from a 3rd party. It talks about basics and good material for tile based games, which are great starting points for developing.

Answer (score 1):

http://aigamedev.com/

Half their content is behind a paywall, and it's practically impossible to find anything specific (like if you're trying to find their articles on behavior trees), but the content is second to none.

Comment: The material there has looked good the several times I've visited, but nearly everything you have to pay for (i.e, after playing L4D a lot I looked at those articles. You have to pay for them. Shame, because the AI director is seriously amazing.) And it seems to be advanced, mostly.

Comment: That site probably has some amazing content, I think they targeting industry professional more.