# 2D AI Engines/ Resources?

Tags: c++, 2d, architecture, ai, box2d

i'm wondering if there's any 2D AI source code or engines out there. I'm inspired by  the [Euphoria engine](http://www.naturalmotion.com/euphoria), and want to use whatever is already out there to make something like it in 2D, where the characters can move left and right, and attempt to preserve themselves. The only new feature i would want to add on is ability to *learn from common results after an action.*

I'm thinking the way it would work is you attach some AI to a character, and it determines movement/detection based on the number of arms, legs, joints, restrictions, and other movement-related body parts.

*anything relating to AI would probablly be helpful as i've never worked with it:*

**How do you guys suggest i get started? *(Btw: i'm using box2D/ SFML at the moment)***

oh yeah and preferably open source =)

Comment: Based on the bold, I want to say duplicate of http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2194/new-to-creating-ai-where-to-start

Comment: @The Communist Duck If you read the whole question, it really has noting to do with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it seems you want is completely procedural character locomotion, I doubt very much that this exists in free-interwebs space.

In games like Spore, the locomotion is partially procedural, this means that you already need base data to say what kind of movement each limb can produce, etc. You could really take this as far as you want, the easiest is to start with saying that a character uses his legs for walking, and go from there.

[Ken Perlin](http://cs.nyu.edu/~perlin/) does research on actor movement and expression.

Here is a semi-procedural (3D) walking in Unity :
http://runevision.com/thesis/

And a 2D version :
http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?217356-Procedural-Bipedal-Locomotion-Animation-System

As you can see, the aim is adaptability to a terrain and both use a basic knowledge of how a person walks. The Euphoria engine works in pretty much the same way; simply put it's a mix between ragdoll physics and animations.

On the other end of the spectrum, you could give a creature limbs that can move in a certain way, and let physics show what the end result is.

The hardest part would be to let your creature learn from his mistakes, typically using a Neuronal Network, so it can learn how to walk faster, with more stability, etc.

Comment: is the source code for any of this stuff like Ken Perlins things avaliable?

Comment: @Griffin I'll try and have a look this week-end to see if I can find any resources, but I'm pretty sure the best you'll find is research papers.

Comment: @3nixios Alright Thanks! That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Its not exactly AI you should be looking for. Its (Human) Motion Synthesis.

Euphoria is the only product is the market that can do so. Googling, bring up some research result, but they are 3d. So, for 2d I think writing your own might be the only solution.